# can we use flutter, also for Blackberry OS and Windows OS mobile application creation

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

as per many sides, flutter is also supported desktop application.
but for other mobile operating systems like  Blackberry OS and Windows OS
can we use it.

Answer (score 0):

> Flutter is Google’s UI toolkit for building beautiful, natively compiled applications for mobile, web, and desktop from a single codebase.

For building desktop apps, Windows OS and Linux is still under development.

To read more on the releases and support platforms of Flutter, check the links below:

**MOBILE** => [Mobile](https://flutter.dev/docs)

**WEB** => [Web](https://flutter.dev/web)

**DESKTOP** => [Desktop](https://flutter.dev/desktop)

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: but is it any video or blog that can describe how to use this for windows os and blackberry os.

Comment: For windows, try this link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells. For blackberry OS, I don't think Flutter has a support for that @shirsh

Comment: "Work is ongoing to extend Flutter to support desktop as a target environment, allowing developers to create macOS, Windows, and Linux applications with Flutter."

It means they are not available now.

Comment: Check my answer above, I said Windows OS and Linux is still under development. @shirsh